# Replace Text with Content Editable in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contenteditable

const Str =
'Your name +++Vijay+++Welcome to hello world '

I want to replace Vijay with reactJS content editable, where i can change the name.

Comment: What did you do for this

Answer (score 1):

you can use string template to do that
try

```
const changeStr = (name = "USER_NAME") => `Your name ${name} Welcome to hello world`
```

then

```
changeStr('Vijay')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the replace function https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

```
let Str = 'Your name +++Vijay+++Welcome to hello world '
Str = Str.replace("Vijay", "something you want")
```

Comment: will check on it